# Tulipy Cannot convert Series to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

During the installation of tulipy i've seen that my numpy version was obsolete, but I tried to upgrade and I checked that it was at the last version.
The problem is that if i call:

```
    import tulipy as ti   
    def view(data, ma_check, ma_lenght):
        if ma_check == 1:
            ma = ti.sma(data, ma_lenght)
    ma = view(data['close'], 1, 20)
    print(ma)
```

output:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert Series to numpy.ndarray
```

but if I put `data['close'].values` instead of `data['close']` (so converting the series before tulipy does) inside, the function works perfectly.
Is tulipy recognizing another version of numpy? How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error does not concern the version of `numpy`. As you can see from the error message, the error is a [*TypeError*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError): i.e. you are passing the wrong type. As stated in the documentation for [`tulipy`](https://pypi.org/project/tulipy/):

> Tulipy requires numpy as **all inputs** and outputs are numpy arrays (dtype=np.float64).

Yet with `data['close']` you are passing a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html). The function call works with [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html), since this "[return[s] Series as ndarray or ndarray-like depending on the dtype".

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'close': [0.1,0.2]})

print(type(data['close']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(data['close'].values))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

N.B. It is now recommended that you use [`pd.Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas.Series.to_numpy) instead of `pd.Series.values`. Note also that the `dtype` needs to be `np.float64`. So, you can check this as well:

```
print(type(data['close'].to_numpy().dtype))
<class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>
```